# Layout, CSS table, table-cell and an ugly gap on aside column

Tags: css, html, css-tables

I'm having issues with creating equal height columns on the basic Dreamweaver HTML5 3 col fixed layout. I was using jQuery equal height columns to make the column's bg colour be equal on all pages, however due to some scripts I am using on my site and incompatibility with a manual "style:height:xpx" added to the article column I would like to try and use the display:table, `display:table-cell` method. I have used the basic Dreamweaver 5.5 HTML5 template, and kept everything the same except removed the `display:block` property for aside, article etc elements. I added a container div around the 3 columns; aside, article and aside.

Everything works fine - as in the background colour continues until the end of the block, which is what I need - except the trouble is, for some reason on the aside columns it leaves a gap at the top of the columns of 13px. I have no idea why this is happening.

I have uploaded the file here: http://www.primecuts.org.uk/test.html . If I remove the `<nav>` part, the gap is still there, although it doesn't look as "ugly" as the bgcolor difference is not noticeable, I would like there to be no gap between the text starting and the top of the block/bottom of the header. Any help would be appreciated, I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: I have noticed if I remove all padding in the CSS for .sidebar1, .content and aside the gap is reduced but there is still a 3px gap.

Comment: For the sake of longevity (and in case you start messing around with the live site), here is the code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZR2H/1/

Comment: I'm baffled. Hope you get a solution. `.sidebar1 { float:left; }` removes it, but of course ruins the layout.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be fixed by

```
.sidebar1 { vertical-align:top; }
```

The gap has something to do with the padding on the .content article, in the sense that removing padding removes the gap, and the padding is influencing the position of sidebar because they are both table cells in the same table row, but I confess that's a bit of a woolly explanation, and I can't actually identify the specific CSS requirement that this relates to.

Comment: Ah the elusive `vertical-align`... nice catch. I guess this is a symptom of the table-cell display?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. Finally a 3 col layout that actually works, the "holy grail" method I've seen mentioned is amazingly complicated and does not allow you to use background images in your columns. Thanks again.